# How do I make a popover not flicker in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple scenario where I have div tag which when the mouse hovers over it, displays an overlay with more information (using jquery and jquery ui). The problem I'm getting is that the overlay flickers when the mouse hovers over it:

```
$('#myobject').hover(function() {
  $popover = $('#popover');
  $popover.show();
  $popover.position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "left top",
    of: $(this)
  });
}, function() {
  $('#popover').hide();
});
```

Obviously I have to do something where moving the mouse on the popover doesn't kill the hover event, but I'm not sure how to do this. You can see the scenario running here: **http://jsfiddle.net/vRH3Q/2/**

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the child `<div>` within the parent `<div>`:

```
<div id='myobject'>
    My Object
    <div id='popover'>My Popover</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRH3Q/5/)

Comment: Nice...although my answer works, I like this one too. +1 Is there any reason you would (or would not) want to do one versus the other?

Comment: Thanks.  I like its simplicity, but I believe a problem would arise if you want the child `<div>` aligned absolutely to the page and your parent `<div>` has `align: relative`.  It works great when the child needs to align relative to the parent, though.

Comment: Ah, good point. Well, either way, still +1 for the simplicity of it.

Comment: Sorry @Keltex, I'd try one of the other answers then.

Answer (score 2):

It flickers like that because the 'hover' event is attached to `#myobject`. When you move your mouse around, the mouse is NOT hovering over `#myobject` because you have `#popover` over top `#myobject`. So, you are rapidly moving between `#myobject` and `#popover` causing the flicker to happen.

A better solution is to use a combination of mouseover and mouseout.

```
$('#myobject').mouseenter(function() {
    $popover = $('#popover');
    $popover.show();
    $popover.position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $(this)
    });
});

$('#popover').mouseout(function() {
    $('#popover').hide();
});
```

I have updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRH3Q/4/).

Comment: Almost works. The problem is if you do a "flyby" very quickly it can leave the popover visible. Same for the other similar answers.

Comment: @Keltex - Huh...very interesting. Didn't notice that...let me take a look.

Comment: I can make it happen if I go over the corner quickly. Basically I think what happens is that in this scenario, the mouse is never "in" #popover so the mouseout event doesn't happen.

Comment: @Keltex - Yes, I believe you are right. Any way you can position the $popover without having to move it to "left top" after the fact?

Comment: Unfortunately it's part of the design that the popup obscures the object. One option I was considering is setting up `setInterval` to poll to see if the mouse is outside the popup...

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the mouseleave event on #myobject and add it to the #popover element:

```
$('#myobject').bind('mouseenter',function() {
    $popover = $('#popover');
    $popover.show();
    $popover.position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $(this)
    });
});

$('#popover').bind('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vRH3Q/2/

Comment: Almost works. The problem is if you do a "flyby" very quickly it can leave the popover visible. Same for the other simlar answers.

Answer (score 0):

Once the `popover` div is shown jQuery thinks it is no longer hovering over `myobject`, move your mouse and the loop continues causing the flicker.

This works:

```
$('#myobject').mouseenter(function() {
    $popover = $('#popover');
    $popover.show();
    $popover.position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $(this)
    });
});

$('#popover').mouseout(function() {
    $('#popover').hide();
});
```

A clunky workaround (that might in certain scenarios depending on your need) to fix the "corner" problem is to make sure the popover is closed whenever the mouse goes back to the body of your page, by adding this:

```
$('body').hover(function() {
    $('#popover').hide();
});
```

Comment: Almost works. The problem is if you do a "flyby" very quickly it can leave the popover visible. Same for the other simlar answers.

Comment: @keltex - ok, added a possible workaround for your 'corner' issue. Because of the way jsFiddle's frames are setup this will work better on a full page: jsfiddle.net/vRH3Q/13